# Ajax not working properly

Tags: functions, customization, ajax, forms

I'm working an Ajaxifying form. This form is a custom page template. The saving of the data is working, but when the form is submitting, the page is redirects to `websiteurl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` with a white blank page. What I want is to prevent the reloading of the page. I didn't receive any error message from `error function`.

How to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" id="modal-form-ajax" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_title" value="Resume"/>
        <input placeholder="Last Name*" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" required data-selectable="true">
        <input placeholder="First Name*" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" required data-selectable="true">
        <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="Email" id="Email" onblur="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" required data-selectable="true">
        <input placeholder="Mobile Number*" type="text" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="" size="11" minlength="11" maxlength="11" pattern ="^09\d{9}$" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter your 11-digits Philippine mobile number')" onchange="try{ setCustomValidity('') } catch(e){}" required data-selectable="true">
        <div class="flex">
            <label>Upload CV & Cover Letter</label>
            <input placeholder="CV" type="file" name="Resume" value="" required>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="validate_form_modal"/>
        <?php wp_nonce_field('validate_form_modal_nonce', 'name_of_nonce_field'); ?>
        <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
(function($){
    $("#modal-form-ajax").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var resumetest = $('input[name="form_title"]').val();
        var lastName = $('input[name="lastName"]').val();
        var firstName = $('input[name="firstName"]').val();
        var Email = $('input[name="Email"]').val();
        var contactNumber = $('input[name="contactNumber"]').val();
        var ajaxUrl = { ajaxFormUrl: '//websiteurl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' }
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajaxUrl.ajaxFormUrl,
            data: {
                action: 'validate_form_modal',
                lastName: lastName,
                firstName: firstName,
                Email: Email,
                contactNumber: contactNumber,
                Resume: Resume
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Thank you for your application");
                console.log($('#modal-form-ajax').serialize());
                $("#modal-form-ajax").fadeOut('ease',function(){
                  $("#modal-form-ajax").html('<div id="modal-form-success"><div class="circle-loader"><div class="checkmark draw"></div></div><p>Thank you for your application</p><p>We\'ll get back to you shortly.</p></div>');
                  $("#modal-form-ajax").fadeIn('ease');
                });
              },
            error: function(){
                alert(response);
            }
          });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**PHP (functions.php)**

```
function ajax_modal_form_init(){
    wp_localize_script('ajax-modal-form', 'modalFormAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-modal-form');
}

add_action('wp_ajax_validate_form_modal', 'validate_form_modal');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_validate_form_modal', 'validate_form_modal');
function validate_form_modal(){
    ob_clean();
    global $wpdb;

    if(!isset($_POST['name_of_nonce_field']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_of_nonce_field'], 'validate_form_modal_nonce')){
        exit('The form is not valid');
    }

    $lastName               = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? filter_var($_POST['lastName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) : '';
    $firstName              = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? filter_var($_POST['firstName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH) : '';
    $email                  = isset($_POST['Email']) ? filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) : '';
    $contactNumber          = isset($_POST['contactNumber']) ? filter_var($_POST['contactNumber'], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP) : '';

    echo do_shortcode("[cfdb-save-form-post]");

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: The script isn't running at all, how are you loading it?

Comment: the js script is written in one page with the html (custom page template)

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I already to separate the js script but still same issue

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the way you have your AJAX URL structured is different than anything I've seen before.  I normally just use: `var ajaxurl  = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';` - not sure if that'll change anything but since the page is redirecting to the url after success maybe that's part of it?

Answer (score 1):

Just saw it... ...in your HTML, take the action out entirely.  We're not using the HTML to tell the form/submit button what to do, we're using JS/AJAX for that.

`<form method="POST" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" id="modal-form-ajax" autocomplete="off">`

Should become:

`<form method="POST" id="modal-form-ajax" autocomplete="off">`

Also, instead of targeting the form, target the submit button, so the following:

```
$("#modal-form-ajax").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
```

Should become:

```
$("#submit-btn").on('click',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

1. Put the submit button outside the form and bind the js-function to the button instead `$('#submit-btn).on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...})`.
2. Try to `return false;` and the end of your script, right after `$.ajax({...});`.

Read more in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121958/jquery-ajax-post-inside-a-form-prevent-form-submission-on-ajax-call).

Comment: I tried to put the `button` tag outside the form. The form is not now refreshing after submit, but the form data is not saving and the `success fuction` is not display

Comment: I also followed the solution in the link that you provided, but still no luck :(